# scipy.optimize returns initial guess when input parameters are small

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I Need to find the Minimum variance Portfolio using scipy optimize. I have the following covariance Matrix:

```
[[0.00076593 0.00087803 0.00082423 0.00094616 0.00090782]
  [0.00087803 0.0015638  0.00086395 0.00097013 0.00107642]
  [0.00082423 0.00086395 0.00092068 0.00104474 0.00099357]
  [0.00094616 0.00097013 0.00104474 0.00133651 0.00119894]
  [0.00090782 0.00107642 0.00099357 0.00119894 0.00132278]]]
```

And the initial guess for Portfolio weights is:

```
[0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2]
```

Running the following Code, where V is the covariance Matrix from above:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from tqdm import tqdm

#Minimum Variance

cov_rol = df_smartbeta.rolling(window=36).cov()
cov_rol = cov_rol.values.reshape(665,5,5)
V = cov_rol

def objective(w, V): #portfolio variance, 1x1 array
    w1= np.matrix(w)
    wt = np.matrix(w1)
    wt = np.transpose(wt)
    return (w1*V)*wt

def constraint1(x): #constraint 1: sum w0 = 1
    return np.sum(x)-1

w0 = np.array([0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2]) #initial guess
cons = ({"type":"eq", "fun": constraint1}) #merge constraints
b = (0,None) #define bounds. Lower bound: 0. Upper bound: None
bnds = (b,b,b,b,b)

count = 0
w_min = []
for i in tqdm(range(len(cov_rol))):
    res =minimize(objective, w0, args=(V[count]), method="SLSQP",bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
    w_min.append(res.x)
    count += 1

w_min_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(w_min)
```

The Code just Returns the initial guess, although it should yield

```
[1.0,0,0,0,0]
```

If I rescale the covariance Matrix by multiplying with 100, the Code works. Does anyone know why this is Happening and how to solve the issue without rescaling? I have seen some similar questions before but havent found any Solutions that work...

Comment: Please show all your imports too, that makes it easier to copy&paste.

Comment: Additionally you should avoid using np.matrix, it is more standard to use np.array. you could just do w1.T @ V @ w1 with w1 and V two bumpy arrays, in python 3.6

Comment: I just edited the Imports.

Comment: I believe `optimize` has some test that it uses to check whether it's converged yet. If so, it stops early instead of using the maximum allowed number of steps. It may be that because your values are small, it's seen as converged sooner?